# Dynamic form in Ionic 3 using JSON response

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am new to ionic and trying to make a dynamic form based on Json Response. I have tried using Formbuilder, and successfully implemented the UI of form but I dont know how to get data from the form in Json format.

Below is the html for the form:

```
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>newsDetails</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

<form [formGroup]="formdata" (submit)="submitForm(formdata.value)">
  <ion-card >
    <ion-list padding *ngFor="let details of jsondetails?.product_options">
        {{details.option_name}}
      <ion-card-content>
          <ion-item *ngIf="details.option_type == 'S'" >
            <!--<ion-label>{{details.option_name}}</ion-label>-->

              <ion-select formControlName="details.option_name" >
                  <ion-option *ngFor="let key of details?.variants" value="{{key.variant_id}}"
                  >{{key.variant_name}}</ion-option>
              </ion-select>


          </ion-item>


          <div *ngIf="details.option_type == 'R'" >
           <ion-list radio-group formControlName="details.option_name"  >

             <ion-item *ngFor="let key of details?.variants">
               <ion-label>{{key.variant_name}}</ion-label>

              <ion-radio item-left value = "{{key.variant_id}}">{{key.variant_name}}</ion-radio>

            </ion-item>   
</ion-list>


          </div>

          <div *ngIf="details.option_type == 'C' ">

            <ion-list formControlName="details.option_name">
              <ion-item *ngFor="let key of details?.variants ;let i = index">
              <ion-checkbox (ionChange)="onChange(key.variant_id, $event.checked, i)" value="key.variant_id"></ion-checkbox>
              <ion-label>{{key.variant_name}}</ion-label>
            </ion-item>                  

         </ion-list>
          </div>

          <ion-item *ngIf="details.option_type == 'T'">

              <ion-label floating>{{details.option_name}}</ion-label>
                <ion-textarea #myInput id="myInput" rows="1" maxLength="5" [(ngModel)]="model" 
                formControlName="details.option_name">
                </ion-textarea>

          </ion-item>

      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-list>

      <button ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="!formdata.valid">Submit</button>
  </ion-card>
</form>
</ion-content>
```

Below is the TS code:

```
export class NewsDetailsPage {

    public formdata : FormGroup;
    jsondetails: any;
    public selectedArray :any = [];
    //items: FormArray;
    pusheditems = {};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    console.log('111');
   this.ionViewDidLoad();

      this.formdata = this.formBuilder.group({
          // items: this.formBuilder.array([ this.createItem() ])

          //spinner: [''],
          //radio: [''],
          //checkbox: [this.selectedArray],
         // text: ['']
        });

  }

//This is the Dummy JSON which I am using to create form:

  ionViewDidLoad() {
     this.jsondetails = {
        "product_options": [
            {"option_type": "C","value": 62,"option_name": "Accessories",
                "variants": [
                    {"variant_id": "62","position": "1","variant_name": "Ear-phones","formatmodifier": "$30.00"},
                    {"variant_id": "61","position": "2","variant_name": "Head-phones","formatmodifier": "$10.00"},
                    {"variant_id": "63","position": "3","variant_name": "Blutooth-speakers","formatmodifier": "$50.00"}
                ]},
            {"option_type": "S","value": 55,"option_name": "Color",
                "variants": [
                    {"variant_id": "55","variant_name": "White","image_pair": [],"formatmodifier": "$0.00"},
                    {"variant_id": "56","variant_name": "Black","image_pair": [],"formatmodifier": "$0.00"},
                    {"variant_id": "57","variant_name": "Blue","image_pair": [],"formatmodifier": "$0.00"},
                    {"variant_id": "58","variant_name": "Red","image_pair": [],"formatmodifier": "$0.00"},
                    {"variant_id": "59","variant_name": "Green","image_pair": [],"formatmodifier": "$0.00"},
                    {"variant_id": "60","variant_name": "Yellow","image_pair": [],"formatmodifier": "$0.00"}
                ]},
            {"option_type": "R","value": 54,"option_name": "3G Connectivity",
                "variants": [
                    {"variant_id": "54","variant_name": "NO","image_pair": [],"formatmodifier": "$0.00"},
                    {"variant_id": "53","variant_name": "YES","image_pair": [],"formatmodifier": "$125.00"}
                ]},
            {"option_type": "S","value": 49,"option_name": "Memory capacity",
                "variants": [
                    {"variant_id": "49","variant_name": "16GB","image_pair": [],"formatmodifier": "$0.00"},
                    {"variant_id": "50","variant_name": "32GB","image_pair": [],"formatmodifier": "$100.00"},
                    {"variant_id": "51","variant_name": "64GB","image_pair": [],"formatmodifier": "$200.00"},
                    {"variant_id": "52","variant_name": "128GB","image_pair": [],"formatmodifier": "$300.00"}
                ]},
            {"option_type": "T","value": 42,"option_name": "Comment"}
        ]
    };
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad NewsDetailsPage');
    this.getItems();

  }

submitForm(fd){
    console.log(fd)
  }

    getItems() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.jsondetails.product_options.length; i++) {
      this.pusheditems[this.jsondetails.product_options[i].option_type] = '';
     console.log(this.jsondetails.product_options[i].option_type);

    }
     console.log(this.pusheditems);

  }

 onChange(id, isChecked, index) {

   if(isChecked) {
        this.selectedArray.push(id)
         console.log(this.selectedArray)
    }
    if(!isChecked) {
        //this.selectedArray.push(id)
         const index: number = this.selectedArray.indexOf(id);
         console.log("INDEX---"+index)
    if (index !== -1) {
        this.selectedArray.splice(index, 1);
    }  
         console.log(this.selectedArray)
    }

    console.log(this.selectedArray)
}

//  private addItemForm= this.formBuilder.group({
//     selectedItem: [],
// });



}
```

I know My code is not correct please help me understand the correct method to implement dynamic form. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't get JSON data from form. You have to create a JSON object or JSON array  whatever you want.

Comment: I don't want json data. I want values from the form and store it in json format. But  main issue is how to bind HTML with TS so that I can capture value entered in form

Comment: oh its as simple as you said :) Just use `[(ngModel)]="NameYouWant"` in the html file and in ts file you need to declare that name to the public and global so you can get the details that you enter in the html file. and yaa dont forgot to add `name="NameYouWant"`otherwise the error will come

Answer (score 0):

in html file do like this

```
<ion-select formControlName="details.option_name" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" name="selectedValue" >
              <ion-option *ngFor="let key of details?.variants" value="{{key.variant_id}}"
              >{{key.variant_name}}</ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

and in ts file

```
public selectedValue:any;
console.log(selectedValue)
```

it will logged your selected value from the select.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Mustafa, For this approach I have some questions, 1. What about Formcontrolname do I still need it. 2. Like I said I am creating view of form dynamically using for loop and condition what if I have two select fields, for both of them I will be assigning the same name. Even if I assign name dynamically like i assigned to form control name, how will I declare that name in TS file

Comment: 1) Yes you need it, because you have condition of hide and show the button.
2) Look, I didn't do like this before, so I think you need only one variable, and it returns an array.
3) Globally.